# SSRS Report render issue when data is high

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am able to fetch the report when data is having 20000 rows. But When we have more data like 3 millions rows then report is in rendering (loading) state infinitely for a longer time and we unable to display the report.

we are using the stored procedure to fetch the report. it is taking 2 minutes to fetch the data on SQL serve and in report builder query.

What can we do to fetch the report. Please help me.

Thanks,
Sreenivasa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one will read 3 million rows on a report...

You need to filter your data so less is returned.

You can use Pagination for example by Date so only some of the data is displayed on each report run and the date can be adjusted to look at sub-sections of the data